# Creating Applescript to Rate 5 Stars

Tags: menu, click, applescript

I'm trying to get the program Capture One to rate an item as 5 stars in apple script. I can get the program to access a menu item as long as the item doesn't lead to another menu but unfortunately for me under rating there is an option to select a rating. I can't figure out how to get the script to rate the item. Any help would be great.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    tell application "Capture One" to activate
    tell application "System Events"


        try
            click menu item ¬
                "5" in menu "Rating" in menu "Adjustments" of menu bar item ¬
                "Adjustments" in menu bar 1 of process "Capture One"

        end try

    end tell
```

Here is an image of the menu bar where I'm trying to select Rate 5 from.

[image: Menu Bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give a rating with a number keystroke?

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "5"
```

Comment: Yes you can. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the menu item is "5". That is the keystroke that you can click to choose 5-star.
So, the menu item is perhaps five asterisks?  "*****"

Here is how we have coded clicking sub-menus:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Capture One 10"
    set frontmost to true
    click menu item "Capture" of menu 1 of menu item "Select Tool Tab" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1

end tell
end tell
```